# matplotlib dynamic text by last value

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

hello i want to create a matplotlib animation and i used this code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (17,12))
plt.rcParams.update({"font.family":"Sahel", "font.size":26})

n= 150
t = [int(i) for i in np.linspace(0,len(df1)-1,n)]
t1 =list(np.arange(0,n))
y1 = [df1["stock"].iloc[i] for i in t]
y2 = [df1["gold"].iloc[i] for i in t]


# scat = ax.scatter(t[0], z[0], c="b", s=5, label=f'v0 = {v0} m/s')
line1 = ax.plot(t1[0], y1[0], label=get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("شاخص کل")))[0]
line2 = ax.plot(t1[0], y2[0], label=get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("سکه")))[0]
ax.set(xlim=[0, n], ylim=[df1[["stock","gold"]].min().min(), df1[["stock","gold"]].max().max()], 
       xlabel=get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("زمان")), ylabel=get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("درصد")))
xx = [int(j) for j in np.arange(0,len(df1),len(df1)//7)] 
xxx = [en_to_fa(JalaliDate(datetime.date.fromisoformat(df1["time"].iloc[j])).isoformat()) for j in xx]
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,n,20), xxx, rotation = 90)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,3600,500), [en_to_fa(str(i)) for i in np.arange(0,3600,500)])
ax.legend()
ax.grid(axis = "x")

def update(frame):
    print(frame)

    line1.set_xdata(t1[:frame])
    line1.set_ydata(y1[:frame])
    text1 = ax.text(t1[frame], y1[frame], en_to_fa(f'{y1[frame]:.1f}'))

    line2.set_xdata(t1[:frame])
    line2.set_ydata(y2[:frame])
    return (line1, line2, text1)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=update, frames=n, interval=40)
ani.save('test1.mp4',  writer = 'ffmpeg', fps = 30) 
plt.show()
```

and i have problems it showed all value but i want to it show in video just last one:

[image]